# Landau Volume 2 Relativistic Free Particle Lagrangian derivation

Tags: special-relativity, calculus

(This is from Vol 2 of Landau and Lifshitz's Course in Theoretical Physics).

After deriving that the Lagrangian of a Lorentz transformation invariant particle is  of the form $L = -\alpha \sqrt{1-{v^2}/c^2}$, Landau determines the constant $\alpha$ by "expanding $L$ in powers of $v/c$" to get the expression $L = -\alpha c + \alpha v^2/2c$, then determines $\alpha$ equals $mc$ by comparison with the classical kinetic energy formula.

My question is what exactly is going on in the expansion of $L$ in powers of $v/c$ he is talking about. I don't see how to correspond what he is doing with what  I know of the Taylor expansion. Could someone clarify how exactly he is getting the expansion L =  $-\alpha c + av^2/2c$ ?

Comment: What is "a Lorentz transformation invariant particle"? "Lorentz invariant" is a characteristic of a quantity, not of a particle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor expansion is just binomial series
$$
(1+x)^{1/2}= 1+ \frac 12 x+ \ldots
$$

You have too many  $c$'s in the denominator.
$$
-ac\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}\approx -ac\left( 1-\frac 12 \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)+O \left(\frac{v^4}{c^4}\right)\\
= -ac + \frac a2 \frac{v^2}c +O \left(\frac{v^4}{c^4}\right).
$$
So to get $mv^2/2$ you need $a=mc$.